# Why ; showing exception

Tags: java

As I know `;` is an empty statement. It's specified in section [14.6 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.6):

An empty statement does nothing.

EmptyStatement: `;`

Execution of an empty statement always completes normally.

When I used `double defaultValue = 0.0;;` then its working fine but I faced an issue when I used below code then its throw error :

```
public double getX() {
    return x;;  // Throws unreachable code
}
```

Why its throwing an error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a valid statement, but it's also an unreachable statement as specified in [JLS 14.21](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21):

> It is a compile-time error if a statement cannot be executed because it is *unreachable*.

The following text describes how to determine the unreachable statements. In particular:

> An empty statement can complete normally iff it is reachable.
>
> A break, continue, return, or throw statement cannot complete normally.

So as `return` statement cannot complete normally, the following statements within the same block become unreachable.

Answer (score 3):

Java is throwing an error because the empty statement `;` comes *after* your return statement and therefore will never be reached:

```
public double getX() {
    return x;   // your program will always return from getX() here
    ;           // this line will never be reached
}
```

Note that this is caught by the compiler, and there is nothing inherently wrong with the empty statement being there.

The Java compiler enforces this rule to minimize the size of run time bytecode by removing code which will never execute.

Comment: Good to know why the compiler even cares about valid but unreachable code. `upVotes++`

Comment: I'd have thought the compiler is enforcing no unreachable code as a general rule, to minimise bugs caused by code the programmer thought would execute but cannot. Having an empty statement after return is just a special case of that.

Answer (score 1):

Because it follows a `return;` it's always unreachable code as the error suggests.

Any statement that follows an unconditional `return` is, by definition, unreachable. So, sure it's valid; in fact, it could be any valid statement (go ahead and try) and it will behave the same.

It's unreachable because `return` returns *immediately* and therefore no additional code can be executed after it.